# Centos 7 docker-machine "invalid argument: could not find capabilities for domaintype=kvm"

Tags: docker, centos7, docker-machine, kvm, libvirt

With a centos 7 minimal machine, I've run the following commands:

```
yum update -y
yum install -y vim docker wget git net-tools bind-utils iptables-services bridge-utils bash-completion libvirt libvirt-daemon qemu-kvm libvirt-daemon-kvm qemu-img libvirt-python libvirt-client virt-install virt-viewer virt-manager 
yum install -y vim docker wget git net-tools bind-utils iptables-services bridge-utils bash-completion libvirt libvirt-daemon qemu-kvm libvirt-daemon-kvm qemu-img libvirt-python libvirt-client virt-install virt-viewer virt-manager 
wget https://github.com/openshift/origin/releases/download/v3.6.0/openshift-origin-server-v3.6.0-c4dd4cf-linux-64bit.tar.gz
curl -L https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.12.2/docker-machine-`uname -s`-`uname -m` >/tmp/docker-machine && chmod +x /tmp/docker-machine && sudo cp /tmp/docker-machine /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
curl -L https://github.com/dhiltgen/docker-machine-kvm/releases/download/v0.10.0/docker-machine-driver-kvm-centos7 > /usr/local/bin/docker-machine-driver-kvm
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-machine-driver-kvm
usermod -a -G libvirt root

systemctl start docker
systemctl enable docker

systemctl start libvirtd
systemctl enable libvirtd
systemctl restart libvirtd

docker-machine create -d "kvm" \
--kvm-boot2docker-url https://github.com/minishift/minishift-b2d-iso/releases/download/v1.1.0/minishift-b2d.iso \
--kvm-cpu-count 4 --kvm-memory 4096 \
--engine-insecure-registry 172.30.0.0/16 openshift
```

...and get:

```
[root@localhost ~]# docker-machine create -d "kvm" \
> --kvm-boot2docker-url https://github.com/minishift/minishift-b2d-iso/releases/download/v1.1.0/minishift-b2d.iso \
> --kvm-cpu-count 4 --kvm-memory 4096 \
> --engine-insecure-registry 172.30.0.0/16 openshift
Creating CA: /root/.docker/machine/certs/ca.pem
Creating client certificate: /root/.docker/machine/certs/cert.pem
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(openshift) Image cache directory does not exist, creating it at /root/.docker/machine/cache...
(openshift) Downloading /root/.docker/machine/cache/boot2docker.iso from https://github.com/minishift/minishift-b2d-iso/releases/download/v1.1.0/minishift-b2d.iso...
(openshift) 0%....10%....20%....30%....40%....50%....60%....70%....80%....90%....100%
(openshift) Creating SSH key...
(openshift) Failed to create the VM: virError(Code=8, Domain=44, Message='invalid argument: could not find capabilities for domaintype=kvm ')
Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: virError(Code=8, Domain=44, Message='invalid argument: could not find capabilities for domaintype=kvm ')
```

From googling, all I can find are recommendations to add my user to the libvirtd group, and install additional packages, and I *think* I've already incorporated all of those steps into my above script.
What am I missing?